# ¿Cómo obtener el registro mas reciente de una consulta sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, date

Necesito obtener el último registro de cada `producto` que haya tenido una `transaccion` del tipo `'transferencia'`. Pero el problema se da cuando un mismo `producto` ha tenido transferencia mas de una vez, ya que está mostrando los 2 movimientos y solo necesito el último.

Tengo una tabla llamada `transacciones` con las siguientes columnas:
`producto, fecha_transaccion, tipo_transaccion`.

Lo que hago es algo como esto:

```
SELECT max(fecha_transaccion),producto
FROM   transacciones
WHERE  tipo_transaccion = 'transferencia'
```

Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal ves puedas agruparlo por el producto y luego consultar por su fecha mayor.

Esto se hace de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT max(fecha_transaccion),
       producto
FROM   transacciones
WHERE  tipo_transaccion = 'transferencia'
GROUP BY producto;
```

Así en primera instancia buscará entre la agrupación de productos, el cual su fecha sea mayor.

Espero que te sirva. Y si necesitas ayuda, me avisas. Éxito en tu proyecto :D

Answer (score 0):

Para poder hacer esa consulta tienes que agrupar por producto, y quedarte con la fecha más reciente de cada producto:

```
SELECT producto, MAX(fecha_transaccion)
FROM transacciones
WHERE tipo_transaccion = 'transferencia'
GROUP BY producto
```